# Поменять картинку на сайте

Tags: html

Очередна проблема: сайт https://gls-trade.ru
в шапке сайте есть логотип левее и правее. Который левее нужно оставить, а который правее нужно поменять. Често говоря, я никакую картинку вставить не могу.
Подскажите, как можно поменять данную картинку.
Код:

```
<div id="logo">
       
           
       <a href="<?=home_url('/');?>" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="<?=get_template_directory_uri()?>/files/ct_block_148020_logo_u4b1I7R9.jpg"><img src="<?=get_template_directory_uri()?>/files/ct_block_148020_logo_u4b1I7R9.jpg"></a>
               <a href="<?=home_url('/');?>" class="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="<?=get_template_directory_uri()?>/files/ct_block_148020_logo_u4b1I7R9.jpg"><img src="<?=get_template_directory_uri()?>/files/ct_block_148020_logo_u4b1I7R9.jpg"></a>
               
           </div><!-- #logo end -->
```

сама картинка - Имя файла: gls1.png или https://gls-trade.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/gls1.png

Answer (score 0):

смею предположить что картинка находится по этому пути

> files/ct_block_148020_logo_u4b1I7R9.jpg

Вам нужно посмотреть где она задается, либо заменить существующую на вашу с сохранением текущего имени